# python to exe without getting detected as virus

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, nuitka

How can i distribute my Python program without it getting detected as virus (at least for windows defender) since almost all the py to exe packages and apps getting detected as virus no matter the code,
i've tried: Pyinstaller, Nuikta
but both getting detected as virus.
so how can i distribute my app?

Tried pyinstaller and nuikta and got detected as virus

Comment: Depends on your antivirus software.

Comment: @matszwecja say for windows defender

Comment: Using `py2exe.freeze` with setting version, description, company_name and product_name for `version_info` worked for me.

Comment: I think it's also heavily dependent on what the program is actually doing. Disk access, for instance, has a higher tendency to get detected as a potentially harmful program. You can also submit the file to Microsoft directly to be whitelisted, but bear in mind, if you change the program, you'll need to resubmit it with the new hash: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission